# Получение cookies браузером при помощи PHP

Tags: php, cookie

Можно ли как-нибудь получить куки из браузера при помощи php. Куки которые лежат в настройках браузера.

Comment: Свои или чужие? Куки задаются для определённого сайта (url) или части сайта. Политика безопасности запрещает подсматривать "чужие" куки на уровне браузера.

Comment: Если браузер их отправит на сервер в каком-нибудь HTTP-запросе, то можно. Если не отправит, то нельзя

Answer (score 0):

Нет, только свои через $_COOKIE